# MATLAB listen to changes in directory

Tags: matlab

I need to listen to changes in my current directory, i.e whenever a new wav file is added i want a function to execute. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what os are you running, linux/windows?

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/9957-using-net-filesystemwatcher-to-listen-for-new-files) helps.

Comment: @Shai iam using Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I finally found the solution. Following page of mathworks proved really helpful. Any how thanks to everyone :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13810-how-to-pass-variables-to-a-callback-function-and-back-again